# How can one place DataBinding inline code inside of inline c# code?

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, inline

How can I achieve the desired effect?
Here's the code:

```
<% if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(%><%#Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderXml");%><%)){ %>
```

etc., which is placed inside of an `ItemTemplate` inside of a `TemplateColumn`.  In the CodeBehind page I will bind a value to the OrderXml field, which occasionally is `NULL`.

Unfortunately I get compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the brackets before Eval:

`<%# if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderXml")` ...

Comment: This did not work for me.
Here's the whole code:
<%# if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval(Container.DataItem,"ResponseXml"))){%>
<a id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderNumber")+"ResponseXml" %>" href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="show('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"OrderNumber")%>','ResponseXml')">[Show]</a>
<%# }else{ %>
<B>NULL</B>
<%# } %>

No combination of '<%'s with '#'s seems to make the compiler happy.